# User Account Suspension is not working in WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Have configured Idle account suspension in WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 using below steps:

- https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/user-account-suspension/
- Added below configuration in deployment.toml of IS
  `[identity_mgt]`
  `inactive_account_suspention.enable_account_suspension = true`
  `inactive_account_suspension.trigger_notifications_at = "13:00:00"`
- And I am using JDBC as a primary user store in IS:

- Have configured below values under **Account Management Policies-->Lock Idle Accounts** in IS
  `Lock Account After (days) --> 12`
  `Alert Users before account locking in days (comma-separated list) --> 6,7,8,9,10,11`
- However the above configured values are not reflecting in wso2is-5.10.0/repository/conf/identity/identity-event.properties file and it is showing default values as shown below:

  `suspension.notification.delays=30,45,60,75`
  `suspension.notification.account.disable.delay=90`
  suspension.notification.trigger.time=13:00:00

**User account is not locked and didn't receive email notification after exceeding defined Idle Time( last login time).**

Answer (score 2):

There is an already reported [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/8478) as Idle account suspension feature does not work with JDBC User Store as expected in the IS-5.10.0 pack. It has been fixed in the latest release of IS-5.11.0. You can switch to the latest version or otherwise, you can apply a patch with the [fix](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-governance/pull/429).